# How to delete an entire array in Ruby and test with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm fairly new to Ruby and am currently taking a full stack course.  For one of my projects we are building an addressbook.  I have set up how to add an entry to the addressbook, however, I can't seem to figure out how to delete an entry (I make an attempt with the remove_entry method in the AddressBook class below but am not having any luck).  We are also supposed to test first with RSpec, have the test fail and then write some code to get it to pass.  If I didn't include all the info needed for this question let me know (rookie here).  Anyway, here is what I have so far:

RSpec

```
context ".remove_entry" do
    it "removes only one entry from the address book" do
      book = AddressBook.new
      entry = book.add_entry('Ada Lovelace', '010.012.1815', 'augusta.king@lovelace.com')
      book.remove_entry(entry)

      expect(entry).to eq nil
    end
  end
```

AddressBook class

```
require_relative "entry.rb"

class AddressBook
  attr_accessor :entries

  def initialize
    @entries = []
  end

  def add_entry(name, phone, email)
    index = 0
    @entries.each do |entry|
      if name < entry.name
        break
      end
      index += 1
    end

    @entries.insert(index, Entry.new(name, phone, email))
  end

  def remove_entry(entry)
    @entries.delete(entry)
  end
end
```

Entry class

```
class Entry
  attr_accessor :name, :phone_number, :email

  def initialize(name, phone_number, email)
    @name = name
    @phone_number = phone_number
    @email = email
  end

  def to_s
    "Name: #{@name}\nPhone Number: #{@phone_number}\nEmail: #{@email}"
  end
end
```

When testing my code with RSpec I receive the following error message:

```
.....F

Failures:

  1) AddressBook.remove_entry removes only one entry from the address book
     Failure/Error: expect(entry).to eq nil

       expected: nil
            got: [#<Entry:0x00000101bc82f0 @name="Ada Lovelace", @phone_number="010.012.1815", @email="augusta.king@lovelace.com">]

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:49:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02075 seconds (files took 0.14221 seconds to load)
6 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/address_book_spec.rb:44 # AddressBook.remove_entry removes only one entry from the address book
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test that the book.entries association is empty:

```
expect(book.entries).to be_empty
```

As book is a local variable in your test, you will not get a false negative result if you keep your test atomic. Some [best practices](http://betterspecs.org/#single) on rspec.

**Edit**:
You can also check the entry was not in the set:

```
expect(book.entries.index(entry)).to be_nil
```

or test the change of the array length with:

```
expect { book.remove_entry(entry) }.to change{book.entries.count}.by(-1)
```

If you wonder for the `be_xxx` syntax sugar, if the object respond to `xxx?`, then you can use `be_xxx` in your tests ([predicate matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-3/docs/built-in-matchers))

Comment: I don't think `entry` or `book` have `reload` methods in this context. However the `be_empty` expect is nice. My only nit with it is that if the test grows or is reused, there could be a false negative if some other entry was added before.

Comment: You are right! I'm always searching ruby-on-rails questions, but this is pure ruby. I'll update the answer. If you keep your tests atomic, you'll not have problem with this. `book` is a local variable created inside the `it`, then there are no way it will conflict with other test.

Comment: Thanks!  Makes sense to me now!

Comment: Just to be clear, the `be_empty` works but as a rule I like to see tests as explicit as possible in their context. You are testing whether the Ada Lovelace entry is removed, so the expect should simply say that. When you are ready to have 2 or more items in your `book`, `be_empty` will not work -- at some point, you have to specify which entry was removed anyway.

Comment: I think 'Ada L' is incidental, it could be 'fake entry' or "entry #{n}" (generated by a factory), and the test should not change. Also I think asking to `book.entries` if it `be_empty` is pretty straightforward, and it can be understood at first sight.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer edits. The 2nd `expect`, with `be_nil`, is probably the closest answer to the OP's original question. At least this question should help a few folks with `expect` calls on array-like objects.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think your expect has an issue. The `entry` variable is not set to `nil`, but the *entry* inside `book` would be `nil`.

I think something like this would work better:

```
expect(book.entries.find { |e| e.name == "Ada Lovelace" }).to eq nil
```

Better still, your `AddressBook` could have its own `find` method, which would make the `expect` param much nicer, like `book.find(:name => "Ada Lovelace")`.

Finally, I would also put an expect call *before* the `remove_entry` call, to make sure its result equals `entry`.